# Is the supremum of the closure equal to the supremum of the set?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, vector-lattices

Let $X$ be any Banach space and $M\subset X$ be bounded. We know the $\sup(M)\in\overline{M}$ in general. Since $M$ is bounded $\sup_{u\in M}\|u\|<\infty$.

**Question:** Can we somehow write that 
$$\sup_{u\in M}\|u\|=\sup_{u\in\overline{M}}\|u\|,$$ 
where $\overline{M}$ denotes the closure of the set $M$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$\sup(M) \in \overline{M}$ in general"?  Is $\text{sup}(M)$ a real number or an element of $X$?  What is the definition of $\sup(M)$?

Comment: I'm sorry I must have said "in case of real numbers" instead of "in general".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as by definition, every member of $\bar{M}$ is a limit to a sequence of elements of $M$, you can show that $\bar{M}$ is also bounded and that its maximum can not be greater that $M$'s one, otherwise, a sequence of elements of $M$ would converge to something greater that its supremum.

Note that in the case of $\bar{M}$, as we reach it, it is also a maximum.